# How to use django-template in a script instead of jinja2?

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I am writing a management command for Django and I created template files that I parse to create new files.

So far to do that I used Jinja2 but since it is a Django management commands, I would like to switch to django based template.

Do you know how I can set up the template environnement in a django management command file ?

What I am looking for is the equivalent of this jinja2 code :

```
env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('modulo.bin', 'templates/plugin_templates'))
```

**EDIT:** Ok in management commands it will work. But what if I want to use django-template in a normal python script ?

Thanks,

Rémy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set up any environment. You're in a Django command, you can use Django templates.

Comment: Ok but in this case my template needs to be in my project templates directory. I wanted to make a specific templates dir for commands separately from the project templates dir. But here again, I just need to add my bin app in INSTALLED_APP and it will works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Django management commands have access to all django environment variables, as you would normally have in the view.

To load a template, assign it some context, and save the results:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

c = {'var':'value','var2':'value2'}  # values you want to send to the template
content = render_to_string('template.html',c) # rendered template
```

This follows the normal django template rules, so `template.html` should be loadable (in other words, it should be in the 'normal' places django looks for templates; or in a directory listed in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`).